# MySQL select query with ajax in wordpress

Tags: mysql, ajax, wordpress

I am passing variable with ajax to list.php in my twentytwelve template. In list.php I am executing mysql select query but when I see in console I am getting this error:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentytwelve\list.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
```

**My Code:**

search.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Search
*/
get_header();?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#parent_category").change(function()
  {
    var parent_category = $(this).val();
    if(parent_category != '')  
     {
      $.ajax
      ({
         type: "POST",
         url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/list.php",
         data: "parent_category="+ parent_category,
         success: function(option)
         {
           $("#child_category").html(option);
         }
      });
     }
     else
     {
       $("#child_category").html("<option value=''>-- No category selected --</option>");
     }
    return false;
  });
});
</script>

<select id="parent_category" name="parent_category">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select blood group --</option>
    <option value="A1 positive">A1 positive</option>
    <option value="A1 negative">A1 negative</option>
    <option value="A2 positive">A2 positive</option>
    <option value="A2 negative">A2 negative</option>
    <option value="B positive">B positive</option>
    <option value="B negative">B negative</option>
    <option value="A1B positive">A1B positive</option>
    <option value="A1B negative">A1B negative</option>
    <option value="A2B positive">A2B positive</option>
    <option value="A2B negative">A2B negative</option>
    <option value="AB positive">AB positive</option>
    <option value="AB negative">AB negative</option>
    <option value="O positive">O positive</option>
    <option value="O negative">O negative</option>
    <option value="A positive">A positive</option>
    <option value="A negative">A negative</option>
</select>

<select id="child_category" name="child_category">
  <option value="">-- No location selected --</option>
</select>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

list.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['parent_category']) && $_POST['parent_category'] != '')
{   
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT home_location FROM wp_places WHERE blood_group LIKE '".$getGroupType."%'" );
    print_r($result);   
}
?>
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: $wpdb needs context of wordpress, a simple php file needs to include the context

Comment: wpdb is not getting instantiated

Comment: include/require the wp-load.php file, this should work

Comment: @SvenSchneider Hi i have include require_once( dirname( dirname( dirname( dirname( __FILE__ )))) . '/wp-load.php' ); in list.php file and now i am getting blank array in console :( any idea.

Comment: Just as a general tip, you'll probably have an easier time debugging this if you a) disentangle the PHP code from the JavaScript code and b) separate your JavaScript code into small functions that each only do a very small job.

Comment: I guess your require is wrong. Locate the wp-load.php and make a correct require. I don't know your list.php location...

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help. My logic is now working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to include the `wp-blog-header` in your `list.php` then define `$wpdb` as `global` the error you are is due to the definition of `$wpdb` which is undefined

```
<?php include("yourpath/wp-blog-header.php");
 global $wpdb;
if(isset($_POST['parent_category']) && $_POST['parent_category'] != '')
{   
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT home_location FROM wp_places WHERE blood_group LIKE '".$getGroupType."%'" );
    print_r($result);   
}
?>
```